# bookshelf.js locking transactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

Is there a possibility to create atomic database transactions with bookshelf? I'm having a problem with duplicates in the database. The problematic code is as below:

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    var modelLocation = new Models.Location({'name':event.venue});
    modelLocation.fetch({transacting:t})
        .then(function (fetchedLocation) {
            if (!fetchedLocation) {
                modelLocation.save(null,{transacting:t}).then(function (savedModel) {
                    t.commit(savedModel)
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    t.rollback(err)
                });
            }
            else{
                t.commit(fetchedLocation)
            }
        })
})
```

I call the method containing this code almost simultaniously and asynchronously 20 times. From these 20, there are 5 duplicate datasets. This results in around 2-3 duplicates in the database. The current workaround is to wrap the whole thing in a setTimeout with a random timout between 0 and 10 seconds which almost never gives me duplicates. But this is obviously not a production ready solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so in the end, I decided to go with the async.js library and it's queue.
The queue guarantees that maximum n async tasks are executed concurrently. In this case 1.
I made a module which exports a queue instance. This way I can use it across multiple modules. It simply waits for the promise to fulfill.

```
var async = require('async');

module.exports = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    task().then(function () {
        callback();
    });
},1);
```

Then in the module, where I need an "atomic" transaction I have the following code:

```
var queue = require('./transactionQueue');
...
...
queue.push(function(){
    return bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
        var modelLocation = new Models.Location({'name':event.venue});
        return modelLocation
            .fetch({transacting:t})
            .then(function (fetchedLocation) {
                if (!fetchedLocation) {
                    return modelLocation
                        .save(null,{transacting:t});
                }
            });
    });
});
```

It's important to wrap the transaction into a function so it won't get executed right away.

Comment: Couldn't your problem be solved by a UNIQUE key?

What you're trying to achieve is some kind of "transactional absence", this concept is totally new for me. AFAIK no DB implements such mechanism. Are you able to make it work with some other technology?

Comment: I initially wanted to solve it with unique keys but then it just throws errors and you'd have to catch them. So I rather have the manual scheduling of the queries. What I need is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking. Which is a basic db functionality.

Comment: Yes, knex supports tho-phase locking though forUpdate() and forShare(). But on your scenario there is no object to lock or, like I said, a "transactional absence", I think two-phase locking does not cover that.

Comment: this might not work if you deploy your code on multiple nodes/servers.

Answer (score 1):

Since Bookshelf transactions are promises you do not need to explicitly call `commit()` or `rollback()`. Just let the fulfilled promise to commit itself, or you can force a rollback by throwing an exception.

In your code there was apparently a small bug that could be causing the trouble: an argument missing from the `fetch()`'s `then()` -- this argument is the result from the `fetch()` invocation, an instance if the object was found or `null` if not.

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
  var modelLocation = new Models.Location({'name':event.venue});
  return modelLocation
    .fetch()
    .then(function (fetchedLocation) {
        if (!fetchedLocation) {
            modelLocation
              .save(null,{transacting:t});
        }
    })l
});
```

I am not able to test that now, but I hope it helps.

Comment: ooops sorry the missing parameter was due to renaming some variables because of company internal stuff. I triple checked and it's the same now. But the problem didn't go away. I'm now looking into a solution with the queue of async.js.